# If a parallel branch fails in aws step function, then how can i revert the changes of other branch that is done

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have a aws step function workflow and in that i have a parallel task which executes 3 tasks "A","B" and "C" all are running in parallel , then "A" successfully completes it's executeion, "B" and "C" both are still running then if "B" fails , then how can i revert changes of "A" and of "C"(which run partially.).

Comment: You need to create the logic and functions by your self. Step functions don't rollback in time without you program them to. You need to create extra functions and logic for such scenarios.

Comment: Thanks i was thinking to do this only.

Answer (score 1):

As @Riz mentioned, Step Functions does not have any built in rollback options.
One option will be for your parallel state to have a catch which will catch if A B or C fail. If it does, the catch will direct to a cleanup/rollback step within your state machine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).